# Сохранение тайтла кнопки в swift

Tags: swift

только сегодня начал разбираться в UserDefaults в Swift
и возник вопрос, я смог сохранить данные такие как текст лейбла, переменные, но не получается сохранить setTitle кнопки
Может кто знает инициализатор для этого случая? 
точнее даже сохранить она ее как бы сохраняет, но вот когда вывожу код при загрузке приложения, то выдает ошибку
ПРобую вот таким способом только вместо лейбла соответственно setTitle

```
'if let labelDef = userDefaults.object(forKey: "labelDef") {
        labelDisplayScene.text = labelDef as? String
    }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так сохраняем строку:

```
if let buttonTitle = button.titleLabel?.text {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(buttonTitle, forKey: "foo")
        }
```

Вот так получаем:

```
if let str = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "foo") as? String {
            button.setTitle(str, for: .normal)
        }
```

Comment: работает) спасибо))
это получается мы сначала забираем в переменную текст кнопки, а потом уже с этой переменной работает, которая строку только содержит?)

Comment: @VladislavBublik вы вначале извлекаете опционал и далее работаете уже с неопциональной переменной